# How to save JSON file when use it as ExtJs grid store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have developed application which use ExtJs functionality where I should keep my store in json file.

My store looks like this:

```
var Grid1Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: [ 'Something 1', 'Something 2', 'Status' ],
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'resources/buildJsonStore/something.json',
        reader:{
             type: 'json'
        }
    }

});
```

Where something.json is my data. The problem is that I want dynamically add data to my store and after that to save the JSON file. I add data successfully with this:

```
Grid1Store.add(data);
```

where data is some JS array, but how I can insert this data into JSON file which I have used for STORE and save it after that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit files in Javascript that are fetched with HTTP.

To be able to update the data, you should save your data in a database, and have PHP (or your server side language) outputting the file `something.json` (which would rather be `something.php`).

Then you add a `writer` configuration to your `proxy`, like

```
proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    url:'resources/buildJsonStore/something.json',
    reader:{
         type: 'json'
    },
    writer: 'json'
}
```

Your file `something.php` will then have to update the databse with the changed data.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use java for my app so I will send request to my controller from ExtJs and from Controller I will save file with data which I need.